# linux bash script: how to execute command with variable as parameter

Tags: bash

I'm trying to make a bash script to lanch a tar command. I need the tar to have a variable parameter, but I can't have it work... Here it is:

```
i=1
for d in /home/test/*
do
    dirs[i++]="${d%/}"
done
echo "There are ${#dirs[@]} dirs in the current path"
for((i=1;i<=${#dirs[@]};i++))
do
        siteonly=${dirs[i]/\/home\/test\//}
        if [[ $siteonly == "choubijoux" ]]
            then
            exclude='--exclude "aenlever/*"';
        fi
    tar -czf /backups/sites/$siteonly.tar.gz ${dirs[i]} --exclude "tmp/*" --exclude "temp/*" --exclude "cache/*" $exclude
done
```

The tar command execute, but without the parameter `--exclude "aenlever/*"` So I suppose the variable is not taken into consideration... Is there a way to make it accept the variable as parameter?

Comment: Are you sure that the variable "exclude" is set at this point?  Perhaps running with -x or echoing the tar command would help to make sure you are actually invoking it with the value.

Comment: Yes, the exclude is well placed, when I launch it in command line, it does its job

Comment: Not well placed, I was asking if it was set - i.e. defined.

Comment: Ah - I see.  The problem is that you are passing two arguments (--exclude and "...") as a single arugment. tar is expecting them as seperate arguments.  See post below for something that should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better solution is to use an array:

```
        exclude=(--exclude "aenlever/*")
    fi
tar -czf /backups/sites/$siteonly.tar.gz ${dirs[i]} --exclude "tmp/*" --exclude "temp/*" --exclude "cache/*" "${exclude[@]}"
```

Also I think you need to reset the variable for every loop, but that depends on your intention.

```
for((i=1;i<=${#dirs[@]};i++))
do
    exclude=()
```

And I would suggest this simplified format as a whole:

```
#!/bin/bash

dirs=(/home/test/*)

# Verify that they are directories. Remove those that aren't.
for i in "${!dirs[@]}"; do
    [[ ! -d ${dirs[i]} ]] && unset 'dirs[i]'
done

echo "There are ${#dirs[@]} dirs in the current path."

for d in "${dirs[@]}"; do
    exclude=()
    siteonly=${d##*/}
    [[ $siteonly == choubijoux ]] && exclude=(--exclude "aenlever/*")
    tar -czf "/backups/sites/$siteonly.tar.gz" "$d" --exclude "tmp/*" --exclude "temp/*" --exclude "cache/*" "${exclude[@]}"
done
```

Comment: Yes! That'it! Thanks ;-)
And you're right, the variable have to be reset on each loop.

Answer (score 0):

May be you would want to `echo _${exclude}_` before `tar` to make sure the variable contains the value you expect.

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
exclude="aenlever/*"
tar -czf /backups/sites/$siteonly.tar.gz ${dirs[i]} --exclude "tmp/*" --exclude "temp/*" --exclude "cache/*" --exclude "$exclude"
```